# pdAdmin4 cannot connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I have successfully installed `PostgreSQL` and `pdAdmin4` on `Ubuntu 18.04` but facing problem while connecting pdAdmin4 to PostgreSQL. When I enter below configuration in pdAdmin4 and click save, I get this error message

[image]

[image]

I have checked, PostgreSQL is running on port `5432`

```
$ sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1283/postgres
```

**-----Update-----**

Updated file `postgresql.conf` with below line

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Update file `pg_hba.conf` with below lines

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Checking PostgreSQL port

```
$ sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4515/postgres       
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      4515/postgres
```

Comment: are your pgAdmin and postgres running on the same machine?  I think you may need to replace `localhost` with the actual IP address of the machine running postgres.

Comment: can check on `iptables` whether localhost is allowed? also, i forgot, but the pgsql had conf file which says which ip can connect to it.

Comment: @richyen Yes both are on same machine

Comment: @BagusTesa I have updated the question can you please have a look

Comment: Are you able to connect using psql?

Comment: @MurtuzaZ you mean from terminal

Comment: @Atinesh yes from terminal but using psql tool which comes bundled with postgres

Comment: @MurtuzaZ Yes without any problem